# Using Perl to get only the FIRST WORD of every line in a string?

Tags: arrays, list, perl

Suppose I have `my $LIST` which is something like the following:

```
Caterpillar1 is red and hairy
Caterpillar2 is green and schwifty
Caterpillar3 is yellow and schwifty
```

Now what I want to do to list is essentially the equivilant of `awk {'print $1'}`. I want to pull from this the following list:

```
Caterpillar1
Caterpillar2
Caterpillar3
```

How can this be accomplished in perl without utilizing any outside system commands?

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt" 
Caterpillar1 is red and hairy
Caterpillar2 is green and schwifty
Caterpillar3 is yellow and schwifty
```

You can do a line-by-line regex of the input:

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -nle 'print $1 if /^(\w+)/'
Caterpillar1
Caterpillar2
Caterpillar3
```

Or, as in comments, `$ echo "$txt" | perl -nle 'print /^(\w+)/'`

You can also use the line-by-line auto split mode (which is similar to `awk` split on whitespace):

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -lane 'print $F[0]'
Caterpillar1
Caterpillar2
Caterpillar3
```

If that multi line string is a single string, just use a global regex:

```
print "$1\n" while $txt=~/^(\w+)/gm;
```

Or, as in comments,

```
print join "\n", $txt =~ /^(\w+)/mg, '';
```

Comment: Or `print join "\n", $txt =~ /^(\w+)/mg, '';`

Comment: Just another way, yes

Comment: `print $1 if /^(\w+) /;` is a long way of writing `print /^(\w+) /;`. I'm not sure why you added the space, either. It should simply be `/^(\w+)/` or `/^(\S+)/`. `/^(\w+) /` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:
`@list = map { /^(\S+)/ } split /\n/, $str` to get a list of first words of every line in your string.

Or more elegant:
`@list = $str =~ /^(\S+)/mg`

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to turn that string into lines, then use it again to turn lines into words:

```
foreach my $line (split /\n/, $LIST)
{
    print ((split / /, $line)[0]);
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: `split / /` splits on *one* space (meaning two consecutive spaces makes a blank element). You probably want `split ' '`, which splits on one or more whitespaces.